# How to solve complicated equation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have equation of type

```
23/(x+3)  +[ (x-3)/(x+3) ] *2 = 57
```

I want to solve for x with java-script.Is there any javascript library to solve these type of equations.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your equation actually a string you need to parse, or do you just need to calculate this in JavaScript during development?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org/) but you will need to write a Parser for expressions, you can use [Peg.JS](https://pegjs.org/) for this or write the parser yourself. With only handful of tokens it should not be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [expression evaluator](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/) - it allows you to pass expressions into a parser that returns a function object that can evaluate the input you are given it.

Here's an example:

```
var expr = Parser.parse("2 ^ x");
expr.evaluate({ x: 3 }); // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are JavaScript solvers out there that will numerically solve your problem. The non-linear solver that I know of is [Ceres.js](https://github.com/Pterodactylus/Ceres.js). Here is an example adapted to your question. The first thing we have to do is rearrange to the form F(x)=0.

x0 = -2.7999999997597933

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h2>User Function</h2>
<p>This is an example of the solution of a user supplied function using Ceres.js</p>

<textarea id="demo" rows="40" cols="170">
</textarea>

<script>
        async function ceresSolvePowell() {
            const {Ceres} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Pterodactylus/Ceres.js@latest/dist/ceres.min.js');
    
            var fn1 = function f1(x){
                //You have to rearrange your function to equal zero 23/(x[0]+3)+((x[0]-3)/(x[0]+3))*2=57
                return 23/(x[0]+3)+((x[0]-3)/(x[0]+3))*2-57;
        }
    
            let solver = new Ceres()
            solver.addFunction(fn1) //Add the first equation to the solver.
            
            var x_guess = [1] //Guess the initial values of the solution.
            let s = await solver.solve(x_guess) //Solve the equation
            var x = s.x //assign the calculated solution array to the variable x
            document.getElementById("demo").value = s.report //Print solver report
            solver.remove() //required to free the memory in C++
            
        }
        ceresSolvePowell();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```